# JavaFX KeyEvent: Difference between isMetaDown() and isAltDown()

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

Is there any difference between `isMetaDown()` and `isAltDown()` in `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`?
Aren't they the same key?

Comment: You have a nice answer about the Meta issue [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/19565).

Comment: If you have to ask .. let me ask you: do you have an ALT key on your keyboard? Do you have a META key on your keyboard? Are they the same key? (If you only have one of them, then clearly they're not the same key)

Comment: I have always thought that the Alt key was also the Meta key after reading so much documentation in emacs calling the Alt key the Meta key.

Answer (score 1):

Meta and Alt both are different keys on a keyboard if meta key is missing then alt or windows key working as meta key.
So if alt key is configured as meta key and alt key then both isAltDown() and isMetaDown are same.

Read more here :

- [Meta Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key)
- [JavaFX KeyEvent](http://javafxtuts.com/javafx-keyevent/)